# Trying to list intune devices through deviceCompliancePolicySettingStateSummaries

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, intune

I am trying to retrieve a list of enrolled devices using the microsoft graph api. The authenticated `GET` request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/deviceCompliancePolicySettingStateSummaries`

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "{\"ErrorCode\":\"Forbidden\",\"Message\":\"{\\r\\n  \\\"_version\\\": 3,\\r\\n  \\\"Message\\\": \\\"An error has occurred - Operation ID (for customer support): 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 - Activity ID: dd0e2f48-90b3-49e0-bb9a-b3b02e4b9482 - Url: https://fef.msua08.manage.microsoft.com/DeviceConfiguration_2005/StatelessDeviceConfigurationFEService/deviceManagement/deviceCompliancePolicySettingStateSummaries?api-version=2020-02-21\\\",\\r\\n  \\\"CustomApiErrorPhrase\\\": \\\"\\\",\\r\\n  \\\"RetryAfter\\\": null,\\r\\n  \\\"ErrorSourceService\\\": \\\"\\\",\\r\\n  \\\"HttpHeaders\\\": \\\"{\\\\\\\"WWW-Authenticate\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"Bearer realm=\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"urn:intune:service,bb7003b9-cb7f-44b2-b534-54f84f2f0d63,f0f3c450-59bf-4f0d-b1b2-0ef84ddfe3c7\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\"}\\\"\\r\\n}\",\"Target\":null,\"Details\":null,\"InnerError\":null,\"InstanceAnnotations\":[]}",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "dd0e2f48-90b3-49e0-bb9a-b3b02e4b9482",
      "date": "2020-05-28T11:34:16"
    }
  }
}
```

I am following the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-deviceconfig-devicecompliancepolicysettingstatesummary-get?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just needed to add these resource permissions `DeviceManagementConfiguration.ReadWrite.All` and `DeviceManagementConfiguration.Read.All` in Azure AD permissions.